# Not being able to print a value corresponding to a particular "div" element using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to print both the CVE-IDs "CVE-2013-2566" and "CVE-2015-2808" under References and "tcp 23" which corresponds to **Unencrypted telnet server** using beautiful soup. Couldn't think of a logic for that.

```
 <div xmlns="" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 5px 10px; background: #fdc431; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #fff;">42263 - Unencrypted Telnet Server</div>
    <div xmlns="" style="margin: 0 0 45px 0;">
    <div class="details-header">Risk Factor<div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="line-height: 20px; padding: 0 0 20px 0;">Medium<div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="details-header">Plugin Information: <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="line-height: 20px; padding: 0 0 20px 0;">Published: 2009/10/27, Modified: 2015/10/21<div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="details-header">**References**<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="idm8894160" style="display: block;" class="table-wrapper see-also">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<thead><tr>
<th width="15%"></th>
<th width="85%"></th>
</tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="">
<td class="#ffffff">CVE</td>
<td class="#ffffff"><a href="http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2013-2566" target="_blank">CVE-2013-2566</a></td>
</tr>
<tr class="">
<td class="#ffffff">CVE</td>
<td class="#ffffff"><a href="http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2015-2808" target="_blank">CVE-2015-2808</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
    <div class="details-header">Plugin Output<div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <h2>tcp/23</h2>
```

This is what I have written and I am stuck where I have put the comments.
I am very much a beginner in bs4 so just bear with me please and I have to submit a report tomorrow so, please help.

```html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import urllib.request as urllib2

with open(r"C:\Users\sourabhk076\Documents\CHIDRMUM_DR8016CHI1_CTSINWDB01_9xtqpj.html") as fp:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(fp.read(), 'html.parser')

f = csv.writer(open("Report.csv", "w"))
f.writerow(["Observation", "Port", "CVE-ID"])

medium = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'style':'box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 5px 10px; background: #fdc431; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #fff;'})
####this will search for text "Unencrypted telnet server"####
for x in medium:
    port = x.find('h2')
    cve = x.find('div', class_='table-wrapper see-also').findAll('tr')
    ######## don't know what to do next #############
    obsv = x.text
    portd = port.text
    print([obsv,portd,cve])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('/path/to/some.html') as f:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html.parser')

service = soup.find('div', style='box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; margin: 0 0 10px 0; padding: 5px 10px; background: #fdc431; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; color: #fff;').get_text(strip=True)
cve_ids = [cve_elem.text for cve_elem in soup.select('table > tbody > tr > td > a')]
protocol, port = soup.select_one('table > h2').text.split('/')
print('{}, {}/{}, CVE-IDs: {}'.format(service, protocol, port, cve_ids))
```

**Output:**

```
42263 - Unencrypted Telnet Server, tcp/23, CVE-IDs: ['CVE-2013-2566', 'CVE-2015-2808']
```

Notice usage of [`select()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) that works with [`CSS selectors`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). I also used `>`, which is a [`child combinator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).

> The child combinator (>) is placed between two CSS selectors. It
>   matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are
>   the children of elements matched by the first.

Answer (score 0):

you can search your tags for child tags.  So maybe something like

```
tbody = cve.find("tbody")
for row in tbody.find_all("tr"):
    print row.find_all("td")[1].text
```

Comment: What if I only want to print [obsv, port]. can you suggest something?